# Jquery autocomplete REST

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, rest, jquery

I'm trying to use autocomplete calling a rest service.

I know the service is being called and is working. I have upload the code to here http://dentalo.se/jqueryautocomplete.html if you want to see it.

When debugging the application I coming to error handling and I can see error **jQuery19100165458942915665_1389965229733 was not called** in firebug using chrome but I am receive a http 200

This is the Jquery code

```
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $("#city").autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) { 
        $.ajax({
          url: "/RestService/Dentalo.svc/SearchByText/" + request.term,
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            featureClass: "P",
            style: "full",
            maxRows: 12,
            name_startsWith: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                      return {
                        label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                        value: item.name
                      }
                    }));
          },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(jqXHR);                        
            },
        });
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
      },
      open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
      },
      close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
      }
    });
  });
```

This is response from the REST Service.

```
[
  {
    "AccountingYear": null,
    "Address": "Jakobsbergsgatan 8",
    "AffiliatedCompany": false,
    "BG": "",
    "BankAccountNumber": "                    ",
    "CEO": null,
    "Calendar": null,
    "Campaign": null,
    "CompanyType": {
      "DateAdded": null,
      "LastUpdated": null,
      "Name": "Enskild firma",
      "Status": false,
      "Type": null,
      "UpdatedBy": null
    },
    "CompanyUser": null,
    "CorporateId": "9165013740",
    "CorporateTaxForm": false,
    "County": {
      "Code": null,
      "DateAdded": null,
      "LastUpdated": null,
      "Name": "Stockholm",
      "PrimaryCounty": false,
      "Status": false,
      "UpdatedBy": null,
      "ZipCode": null
    },
    "DateAdded": "/Date(1373350538000+0200)/",
    "DeliveryAddress": null,
    "Direction": "",
    "Facebook": null,
    "Fax": null,
    "GooglePlus": null,
    "HealthInsuranceFund": false,
    "Image": "",
    "LastUpdated": "/Date(1373350538000+0200)/",
    "Latitude": "59.3348825",
    "LinkedIn": null,
    "Longitude": "18.0717269",
    "Mail": "",
    "ModeOfOperation": false,
    "Name": "TANDEMTANDLÄKARNA HANDELSBOLAG",
    "NumberOfEmployees": "1-4",
    "OpeningHours": "",
    "PG": "",
    "Phone": "08-6113121",
    "ReferralRequirements": false,
    "RegistrationDate": "/Date(934408800000+0200)/",
    "State": {
      "Code": null,
      "County": null,
      "CountySeat": null,
      "DateAdded": null,
      "LastUpdated": null,
      "Latitude": null,
      "Longitude": null,
      "Name": "Stockholms län",
      "Status": false,
      "UpdatedBy": null,
      "ZipCode": null
    },
    "Status": false,
    "TurnOverInterval": null,
    "Twitter": null,
    "Url": "",
    "User": null,
    "VATRegistrationNumber": "",
    "ZipCode": 11144
  },
  {
    "AccountingYear": null,
    "Address": "Sveavägen 13-15",
    "AffiliatedCompany": false,
    "BG": "",
    "BankAccountNumber": "                    ",
    "CEO": null,
    "Calendar": null,
    "Campaign": null,
    "CompanyType": {
      "DateAdded": null,
      "LastUpdated": null,
      "Name": "Enskild firma",
      "Status": false,
      "Type": null,
      "UpdatedBy": null
    },
    "CompanyUser": null,
    "CorporateId": "9696742833",
    "CorporateTaxForm": false,
    "County": {
      "Code": null,
      "DateAdded": null,
      "LastUpdated": null,
      "Name": "Stockholm",
      "PrimaryCounty": false,
      "Status": false,
      "UpdatedBy": null,
      "ZipCode": null
    },
    "DateAdded": "/Date(1373350538000+0200)/",
    "DeliveryAddress": null,
    "Direction": "",
    "Facebook": null,
    "Fax": null,
    "GooglePlus": null,
    "HealthInsuranceFund": false,
    "Image": "",
    "LastUpdated": "/Date(1373350538000+0200)/",
    "Latitude": "59.3341650",
    "LinkedIn": null,
    "Longitude": "18.0642502",
    "Mail": "",
    "ModeOfOperation": false,
    "Name": "JANSSON & KARLSSON HB",
    "NumberOfEmployees": "0",
    "OpeningHours": "",
    "PG": "",
    "Phone": "08-102071",
    "ReferralRequirements": false,
    "RegistrationDate": "/Date(976143600000+0100)/",
    "State": {
      "Code": null,
      "County": null,
      "CountySeat": null,
      "DateAdded": null,
      "LastUpdated": null,
      "Latitude": null,
      "Longitude": null,
      "Name": "Stockholms län",
      "Status": false,
      "UpdatedBy": null,
      "ZipCode": null
    },
    "Status": false,
    "TurnOverInterval": null,
    "Twitter": null,
    "Url": "",
    "User": null,
    "VATRegistrationNumber": "",
    "ZipCode": 11157
  }
]
```

Comment: I think you might be calling the wrong service.  None of the elements that you're trying to access exist in the returned data.

Comment: You are using map `data.geonames` but there is no field on returning json called geonames

Comment: What should use instead of **data.geonames**

Comment: The problem is that your returning json has not relation with your client. How can you test returned json? where is your rest url? the url in ajax call is wrong according to me

Comment: The error was at data.geonames as cubuzoa said. I changed to only being data. Thanks cubuzoa. :)

Comment: Welcome, I have added answer for helping to other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using map `data.geonames` but there is no field on returning json called geonames.You need to use like this;

```
success: function (data) {
    response($.map(data, function (item) {
        return {
            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
            value: item.name
        }
    }));
}
```